# Jump out of function in for loop while debugging in visual studio c

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, debugging, pointers

I want to edit some bits of a file. I open file and determine first byte pointer. So, in *ChangeBit* function, replace some bits by 1s.
When I want to debug *ChangeBit* function, in first iteration of for loop, debug cursor jumps out from function and process dose not terminate and code continues to lines after function.
Whats wrong?

```
void changeBit(char *ptr, int bitLen, int startPoint)
{
    ptr += startPoint / 8;
    startPoint %= 8;
    int tmpBit = 1;
    for (int i = startPoint; i < bitLen; i++)
    {
        ptr[i / 8] = (ptr[i / 8] | tmpBit << (7 - (i % 8)));
        //after this line in first iteration, debug cursor jump out of function
    }
}

int main(void)
{
// open and mmap() the file
    hFile = CreateFile(input_file_name, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    bytes_left = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    hMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    stream_pos = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);   

    changeBit(stream_pos,5,0); // not working

    // copy all bytes to other memory but still not working
    char *OutFileContent;
    OutFileContent = malloc(bytes_left);
    memcpy(OutFileContent, stream_pos, bytes_left);

    changeBit(OutFileContent,5,0); // not working

    //write new bits stream to out file
}
```

Is some thing wrong with pointers?

Comment: `changeBit(OutFileContent,5,12);` --> `changeBit(OutFileContent,12,5);`?

Comment: No, *changeBit* function work with any positive offset. and assume that the input file larger than 10 K.

Comment: You missed the point. Your last two parameters appeared to be swapped. Hence the for loop body will never execute as `startPoint` is greater than `bitlen`. Or you need to change the for loop condition.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I edit question. it's from bad example. but problem is not solved yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw the exception using the Exception settings window during debugging mode:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx

Please also check the following code:

```
hFile = CreateFile(input_file_name, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
bytes_left = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
hMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
stream_pos = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
```

I change it like the following sample, it works well in my side:

```
HANDLE hFile = NULL;
HANDLE hMap = NULL;
char *stream_pos = NULL;
LPCTSTR input_file_name = _T("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Test\\test.txt");
DWORD bytes_left = 0;
hFile = CreateFile(input_file_name, GENERIC_ALL, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
bytes_left = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
hMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
stream_pos = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
```

The file used the read only property, if we change the property, it would work well.